# How can I kill an infinite PHP process?

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi to learn from and to experiment with, and I made a program that simply flashes an LED on GPIO pin 29 (with wiring pi) on a pi B+. I made this process infinite with the intention of killing it with another button on my webpage, but I can't figure it out. I can't even seem to stop it SSHing to the pi. this isn't a real problem, because I can restart the pi and turn it off, but it would be good to learn. I want to kill it from my webpage (I'm using an apache server).
here's the code:

```
<?php
   system ( "gpio mode 29 out" );
   while (true){
   system ( "gpio write 29 0" );
   sleep(1);
   system ( "gpio write 29 1" );
   sleep(1);
   header('Location: remoteGPIO.html');
}
?>
```

so can I kill this with another button NOT using javascript? I don't mind using it, but I would like to avoid it. It's no big deal if I can't though.
I start it using this button:

```
<form action="GPIO29FLASH.php"><button>begin</button></form>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use php sessions and an if statement that only allows it to run if session variable is true. Then you can just press the button to toggle session variable to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea might be to use session. Make the end button to go to another php script that will set some session variable to true. Now make your current script to flash once and then reload the page. And if the session variable is set - simply terminate the script. 
It might even work without reloading the page by changing the while loop to `while (!isset($_SESSION['var']) && $_SESSION['var'] !== true)` , but I'm not sure that $_SESSION variable refreshes without reloading the page.
Hope that works.

Comment: Beat me to it by 18 seconds! #%^%$& ;)

Comment: @DannyPhantom how do I declare a session variable? I have another script that tries to change a variable that I (tried) shared with each other by adding "include 'GPIO29FLASH.php';" when it tried to alter the variable to make the condition untrue. (sorry, forgot to mention that I changed the while loop to "while ($i == 1)" and making the stop script (try) to set it to 0

Comment: I'm not sure that will help, because the process is running on my raspberry pi. I can't figure out how that would make the while loop end. (thanks for the speedy responses btw)

Comment: @DannyPhantom the script is separate from the webpage just so you know. it tells the pi to run it itself just by calling it. so after it is called, it no longer has any ties to it other than through the pi

Comment: @Trevader2413 If you think that's not going to help then set up a DB that will keep a record of whether the while loop should still be running or not. This can also be done through a file. When you press the end button the other script will create an empty file. Your PI's while loop will be `while (!file_exists('file.txt')) {
   //do stuff
}
unlink(file.txt) //when the file was created the loop will be terminated and you remove the file so the same thing can be done later`

Comment: @DannyPhantom that's brilliant! although, I am trying to creat a file and it doesn't seem to be working. could you show me some sample code specifically and only to create a file?

Comment: @Trevader2413 `$myfile = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, "Hi");
fclose($myfile);`
The file is not created if you don't close it. But pretty much that's the whole code you need on the STOP page

Comment: I put that code in on the page, ran it with my website's button, and it follows through with no errors, but it does not seem to create the file when I SSH to my pi and use "ls". EDIT: on the bright side, if I manually create toggle.txt (thats what I'm calling the file) it DOES stop! yay! smart man, smart man.

Comment: @Trevader2413 Try to explicitly provide the path where to store the file. Like `fopen('/etc/new/file.txt', 'w');` The directory should exist though

Comment: I found the problem! the php file didn't have access to write to the /var/www folder! so i changed its write area to /var/tmp and It can write now! however, how can I delete the file so it can start/stop again? EDIT fixed it! i was trying 'unlink()' but I forgot the 's around the file name! it works flawlessly now! thank you!

Comment: @Trevader2413 glad it's working :) Good luck with your Pi